# Cypress get element that a child contains

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm trying to find in a table my  row that cy.contains() a specific text.

I cannot do:

```
cy.get("tr").contains("specific text")
```

That will return my span element containing the text

I cannot do

```
cy.get("tr").contains("specific text").parent()
```

beacause the parent of the span my not be my

I cannot do

```
cy.get("tr").contains("specific text").parentUnitl("tr")
```

That will not return the  element

I probably could do

```
cy.get("tr").contains("specific text").parentUnitl("tr").parent()
```

But I think that's becoming really complex for such a simple thing.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do

```js
cy.contains("tr", "specific text")
```

which will return the `<tr>` even though the text is in a descendent `<span>`.

It will also have better retry ability than `cy.get().contains()` if the row loads asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew I was overthinking that :)